# Linux: Chrome crash after signing in account

Tags: linux, google-chrome

I installed chrome on CentOS 7 by editing /etc/yum.repos.d/google.repo

```
[google64]
name=Google - x86_64
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/rpm/stable/x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
```

Everything went well at the beginning.

But once I signed in my account, I could not do any operation such as open a new page, log out, get into the setting page, etc.

What might be the cause?

---

[Update]

I just re-installed the OS and everything went well.
I guess this was due to some improper installation.

Comment: If you run chrome on the command line with `--enable-logging=stderr --v=1` you should get some helpful output to the terminal. You might want to include (an excerpt from) that output in your question. See https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging for more details on the logging options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The info provided by stonecrusher should be useful.